# Difficult Continuity Multivariable Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

WIll you help me understand the following?

$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sin(y-x) & \text{for} & y>|x| \\  \\
0 & \text{for} & y=|x| \\  \\
\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} & \text{for} & y<|x| 
\end{cases}
$

I need to check differentiability and continuity. 
I tried substituting $x= \frac{1}{2} (u-v)   , y=\frac{1}{2} (u+v)$  but it doesn't help me...
Will you help me figure this thing out?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to{0}}{f(x,\,y)}$ along lines $y=kx$ for different $k.$

Comment: Great ! THanks ! . So the limit does not exist at all ! (right?)

Comment: Yes, the limit does not exist.